# How to merge two descending singly linkedlist into one ascending linkedlist using Recursion without any helper method?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, merge, singly-linked-list

I can merge the two **descending** **singly linkedlists** into one descending list with just one recursion, but I don't know how to do to make the result **ascending** instead without creating any helper methods.

This is my code for merging them into descending order. I was trying to modify within this code to make it ascending but failed. Please help me out~

```
public  Node mergeByRecursion(Node node1, Node node2) {
        if (node1 == null) {
            return node2;
        } else if (node2 == null) {
            return node1;
        }

        if (node1.value < node2.value) {
            node1.next = merge(node1.next, node2);
            return  node1;

        } else {
            node2.next = merge(node1, node2.next);
            return  node2;
        }

    }
```

**Here is a picture of the detailed question that I am trying to solve.**

[image: Picture of the original question]

### UPDATE

I have figured out a solution that works, but not sure if it is the best solution and fits the requirement 100% so I made another post for asking a code review. In case, anyone also gets stuck by this question wanna know a potential solution.
[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/244192/226438)

Comment: I don't have time to properly analyze/respond right now, but briefly, reversing a linked list with recursion amounts to recursing to the end of the list and then building the reversed list going out of the recursion. Perhaps you can incorporate that idea in what you have now.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, Due to the constraint of no helper allowed ,I was struggling. But I have worked out a solution that works at least.

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe this would work:

```
public Node mergeByRecursion(Node node1, Node node2) {
    if (node1 == null) {
        return node2;
    }

    if (node2 == null) {
        return node1;
    }

    if (node1.getElement().value < node2.getElement().value) {
        node1.getNext() = mergeByRecursion(node1.getNext(), node2);
        return node1;

    } else {
        node2.getNext() = mergeByRecursion(node1, node2.getNext());
        return node2;
    }
}
```

- You probably don't need to use `head_node` var.
- You can just call `getNext()` since the lists are already sorted.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have just tested it. It goes into an infinite loop and printing the same value.